# How to pass to NFQUEUE only the initial connection packets

Tags: iptables

I am developing an application on top of NFQUEUE that is supposed to drop specific HTTP connections based on the host name. For performance reasons, I would like to tell netfilter to send my application packets until a verdict (pass or drop) is reached. When that happens my NFQUEUE-based application will set the mark using nfq_set_verdict2(). Unfortunately netfilter sends to NFQUEUE packets even after they have been marked, and from userspace I see that incoming packets have always a mark 0 even though if previous connection packets were marked properly to a non zero value.

This is my configuration:

    `iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
    iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -m mark --mark 1 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -m mark --mark 2 -j DROP
    iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -m mark --mark 0 -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
    iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -j CONNMARK --save-mark`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you marking the packets? I can't see any rule that does the marking!

Comment: I have written a simple app that opens the queue 0 and marks them. This is a code excerpt.

 u_int32_t marker = 1;

nfq_set_verdict2(qh, ntohl(ph->packet_id), pass_verdict,marker, 0, NULL));

Comment: Check if packet pass over iptable after NFQUEUE at all. And really have new mark.
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j LOG --log-prefix passed
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -m mark --mark 2 -j LOG --log-prefix marked_2

I suspect you ocassionally make verdict to NF_DROP in NFQUEUE

Answer (score 1):

NFQUEUE is terminal so packet leave `OUTPUT` chain when you issue
nfq_set_verdict. So packet don't reach the save mark. Common solution
is to save the mark in `POSTROUTING` mangle.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
iptables -A OUTPUT -m mark --mark 1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m mark --mark 2 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -m mark --mark 0 -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t mangle -j CONNMARK --save-mark
```

Comment: Beside the double "-t mangle" (one is enough) it works like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The chain `OUTPUT` is not a good chain for this activity. 
You must mark the packets before they leave your host.

Use a chain `POSTROUTING` (mark packets after the routing decision) or `FORWARD` chain (mark packets after initial routing decision, but before the last routing decision made just before the packets are sent out).

Try this:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -t mangle -j CONNMARK --restore-mark

iptables -A FORWARD -t mangle -m mark --mark 1 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -t mangle -m mark --mark 2 -j DROP

iptables -A FORWARD -t mangle -j CONNMARK --save-mark

iptables -A FORWARD -t mangle -m mark --mark 0 -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

Comment: If you don't use a forwarding solution offered by the kernel  because you move a raw data independently I would try to use a PREROUTING chain. I need something for a try.